# No se porque la lista no sale ordenada

Tags: c++, array, dev-c++

Oredene una lista en base a sus años de nacimiento de menor a mayore deben presentar los datos desordenados usar un metodo de ordenamiento entre burbuja o seleccion, presentar la lista ordenada .Modifique este codigo pero no me oredena los datos correctamente, ¿me pueden ayudar a corregirlo o crear un codigo basico nuevo para que cumpla con los requisitos?.

```
introducir el código aquí
#include <stdio.h>
#define NUMERO_PERSONAS 10
#define MAX_NOMBRE 80
typedef struct{
    char nombre[MAX_NOMBRE];
    int nacimiento;
}Personas;

void imprimirLista(Personas[]);
void ordenarLista(Personas[]);

int main() {
    Personas lista[NUMERO_PERSONAS]=
    {
    {"Joselyn  ",1999,},
    {"Karol     ",2015 },
    {"Diego", 2019},
    {"Monserrat ", 2004},
    {"Karen", 2003},
    {"Maria  ", 1880,},
    {"Guillermo     ", 1884},
    {"Joselito", 2007},
    {"Mario j.", 2001},
    {"Jesus", 2014},
    };
    printf("Lista desordenada:\n");
    imprimirLista(lista);
    ordenarLista(lista);
    printf("\nLista ordenada:\n");
    imprimirLista(lista);
    return 0;
}

void imprimirLista(Personas lista[]){
    int i;
    printf("Nacimiento      Nombre\n");
    for(i=0; i<NUMERO_PERSONAS; i++){
        printf("%d\t\t%s\n", lista[i] .nacimiento, lista[i] .nombre);
    }
}

void ordenarLista(Personas lista[]){
    int i, j;
    Personas aux;
    for(i=0; i<NUMERO_PERSONAS-1; i++){
        for(j=i+1; j<NUMERO_PERSONAS; j++){
                aux = lista[i];
                lista[i] = lista[j];
                lista[j] = aux;
            }
        }
}

float promedio(Personas e){
    return (e.nacimiento)/2.0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No tienes una condición en la función que "ordena" los datos, entonces estás intercambiando elementos en cada vuelta del loop, sin importar cuál es mayor o menor. Si le pones la condición para verificar cuál es mayor y menor, ya funciona:

```
void ordenarLista(Personas lista[]){
    int i, j;
    Personas aux;
    for(i=0; i<NUMERO_PERSONAS-1; i++){
        for(j=i+1; j<NUMERO_PERSONAS; j++){
                if (lista[i].nacimiento > lista[j].nacimiento) {
                    aux = lista[i];
                    lista[i] = lista[j];
                    lista[j] = aux;
                }

            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Gracias, me sacaste de un apuro.